# IE7 z-index not working because of layout order

Tags: css, z-index, internet-explorer-7

I have the following website: http://dev.driz.co.uk/phase/about.php

If you view the website in IE7 you will see that the drop-down menu in the top left does not appear above the main content area. This is because of the stupid IE7 z-index bug, however the normal fix of making the parent element have a high index to make it fix the child would not work in this instance as I need the parent header to sit under the main content...

Any ideas on how to fix this based on the layout structure I have? I've tried most of the IE fixes on the net, including a jquery solution that resets the z-indexes in a loop, but none of them have solved the problem.

Comment: have a look here
http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/

Comment: Hi I have tried that already but it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your header a z-index less than your nav element.

IE7 is a pain with z-index, you need to habe a structure like this.

Header - z-index:2
Content - z-index:3
Nav - z-index:4

Along those lines, sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Tried that but then the header sits on top of the content in IE7 when the content should sit on top of the header but the nav above all everything else

Answer (score -1):

I've found that when having problems with z-index in IE, that setting the elements you want to be affected by the z-index to have a relative position.

i.e.

```
#block {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: You NEED position relative or absolute or fixed for z-index to work in all browsers!

Comment: that is clever discovery, since this is acrtually required for z-index to work :-D